# React Refused to load the image 'blob

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

What should I do to fix this error?

I already have this in my webpack.config.json please help. thanks

```
devServer:{https:true,  historyApiFallback: true}
```

and in my package.json

```
"start": "webpack serve --port 9003 --history-api-fallback",
```

> Refused to create a worker from 'blob:' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: localhost:*". Note that
> 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a
> fallback.

and

> Refused to load the image
> 'blob:x**************'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "default-src 'self' https: localhost:*". Note that 'img-src' was not
> explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

.

Comment: Can you try adding the `Content-Security-Policy` header and its value as `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src blob:;` in the devServer headers option?

Comment: @AkshayMathur how?

Comment: I dont know how to put Content-Security-Policy header in my devServer

Comment: Refer to [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverheaders) document @Roger

Comment: something like this:- 
devServer: {
    headers: {
      'Content-Security-Policy': 'default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src blob:;',
    },
  },